# Exclude rows surpassing threshold value

Tags: r, filter, threshold

I have a dataset `df`

```
  field_pointpath                       assetclass_code value
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   50
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   60
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   65
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    70
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    55
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    11
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    67
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    36
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    39
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    33
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    20
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    21
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    22
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    17
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    30
```

I want to filter out `values` for specific `field_pointpath` 
for example:

- C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_**A03**x6KSF_11xaP_ACT
- C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_**A03**x6KSF_11xaP_ACT

  which has a character **A** should not have `value` greater than 60:

***Similarly***,

- C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_**B03**x6KSF_11xaP_ACT,
- C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_**B03**x6KSF_11xaP_ACT

  which has a character **B** should not have `value` greater than 30

Thus output should be

```
                    field_pointpath    assetclass_code  value
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT   6KSFS_6KSF       50
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT   6KSFS_6KSF       60
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT   6KSFS_6KSF       43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         55
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         11
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT   6KSFS_6KSF       20
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         21
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         22
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         17
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT              6KSFS         30
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `regular expression` to filter on `field_pointpath`. I am assuming that you are looking for entries where there is **_A** or **_B** followed by 2 digits. Then you combine that with the filter on `value`:

```
ind <- (grepl("\\_A[0-9]{2}", df$field_pointpath) & df$value > 60) | 
       (grepl("\\_B[0-9]{2}", df$field_pointpath) & df$value > 30)
df[!ind, ]

#                          field_pointpath assetclass_code value
# 1  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    50
# 2  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    60
# 4  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    43
# 6          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    55
# 7          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    43
# 8          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    11
# 13 C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    20
# 14         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    21
# 15         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    22
# 16         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    17
# 17         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    30
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Well this seems to be more subtle approach but substr worked smoothly for me.

Comment: The `substr` approach assumes that  *A/B*  is _always_ at the 20th position in the string. If you can guarantee that you should go for `substr`. If you need to encompass more cases, you may want to return to `regex`.

Comment: I will keep this advice in my mind. At present the data had strings at fixed position.

Answer (score 2):

```
    df[(substr(df$field_pointpath, 20,20)=="A" & df$value <= 60) |
         (substr(df$field_pointpath, 20,20)=="B" & df$value <= 30),]

1  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    50
2  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    60
4  C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    43
6          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    55
7          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    43
8          C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    11
13 C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF    20
14         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    21
15         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    22
16         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    17
17         C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT           6KSFS    30
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
# your data, with 2 lines appended that will not be selected
my_df  <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
text = "field_pointpath                       assetclass_code value
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   50
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   60
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   65
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT      6KSFS_6KSF   43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    70
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    55
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    43
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_A03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    11
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    67
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    36
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    39
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    33
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03x6KSF_11xaP_ACT     6KSFS_6KSF    20
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    21
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    22
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    17
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_B03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    30
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_C03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    30 ## added
C_THDxL_0154x6KSFS_D03xaP_ACT                  6KSFS    30 ## added
")

library(stringr)
    my_df2 <- my_df[ (str_detect( my_df$field_pointpath, "_A03") & my_df$value <= 30) 
| ( str_detect(my_df$field_pointpath, "_B03")  & my_df$value <= 60 ), ]
```

Please, let me know whether this is what you wanted.

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it was throwing a error. Anyways it worked out for me using solution given by other members. Thank you

Comment: I tested the code above again, and it ran smoothly at my end. If you are still interested, can you let me know the error thrown?